# I'm having a difficult time trying to find a place to put a function that transforms a rendered component in React

Tags: reactjs, scope, css-transforms

I've been stuck for a day and a half moving a function around to try to transform the style of a component to place each card in a deck rotated. The cards are rotating, but the previously rendered cards have their rotated values change on every re-render.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you, and please forgive the bowl of spaghetti you're gonna find if you look at the sandbox.

[My Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcarddealer-forked-3b7pp?file=/src/Card.jsx)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./Card.css";

function Card(props) {

  function animateCard(){
    let angle = Math.random() * 90 - 45;
    let xPos = Math.random() * 40 - 20;
    let yPos = Math.random() * 40 - 20;
    let transform = `translate(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px) rotate(${angle}deg)`;
    return transform;
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="Card-container">
      <img
        className="Card"
        style={{ transform:animateCard()}}
        src={props.image}
        alt={props.name}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotated values for previously rendered cards are changing on each re-render because the `animateCard` function is within the 'Card' component and is being called on each re-render.

You should put the `animateCard` function in the `CardDeck` component and whenever you get a new card, call the `animateCard` function to get the transform properties(angle, xPos, yPos), then save the transform properties for each card into the `card` state with `setCard`. Then, you'll pass that `tranform` property as a prop into the `Card` component. This ensures that once that property is generated and saved, it won't be generated again on each re-render.

Here's a functioning [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcarddealer-forked-c00yk?file=/src/CardDeck.jsx)

Comment: Oh this is awesome! I was playing around with the function in the CardDeck component, but didn't think to set the value to state! The original challenge used Class based components, so the teacher just put the function in the constructor and it worked, but I was trying to recreate the challenge using functional components and could not figure it out for the life of me. Thanks!!!